# Add edges to nodes using Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching

help me i want to add edges to nodes using minimum spanning tree

```
   %clc;
%clear all;
close all;
X=imread('d3.jpg');
imfinfo('d3.jpg')
figure,imshow(X)

b = imresize(X,[100,100]);
si = size(b,1);
sj = size(b,2);
figure;imshow(b);

% Binarization
th = graythresh(b);
I = im2bw(b,th);

w = 5;
h = 5;
c=si/w;
r=sj/h;
kl=bwmorph(~I,'thin',inf);
figure,imshow(kl)

R(:,:)=kl(:,:);
I=1;
U1=w;
J=1;
U2=h;
E=1;
for i=1:r
  for j=1:c
B(I:U1,J:U2)=R(I:U1,J:U2);
[x,y]=find(B==1);
CX=mean(x);
CY=mean(y);
CXX(E)=CX;
CYY(E)=CY;
T(I:U1,J:U2)=B(I:U1,J:U2);
J=J+w;
U2=U2+h;
E=E+1;
clear B x y
 %CYY(isnan(CYY)) = [];
 %CXX(isnan(CXX)) = [];
  end

I=I+w;
U1=U1+h;
J=1;
U2=h;

end
%kl(isnan(kl(:,1)),:) = [];
imshow(R)
hold on

hold on
plot(CYY,CXX,'.c')
hold off
r = imread('empty.jpg');
re = imresize(r,[100,100]);
figure,imshow(re)
hold on
hold on
plot(CYY,CXX,'.k','Markersize',8);
hold off
```

this my code i am getting nodes but i want to connect to nodes using minimum spanning
[this is my output image i want to add edges to this image using minimum spanning tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUtRN.jpg)

Comment: What does your code do? What results do you expect? What results do you get? How (specifically) is your code not working correctly? None of your code seems to actually contribute to finding the minimum spanning tree, so is it really relevant to clarifying your question?

Comment: I want to add edges to each nodes

Comment: So I hear you say.

Comment: I want to represent the word in graph am getting only nodes I want to add edges to nodes.

Comment: We need something more than "I want this to happen". You have your nodes, so what minimum spanning tree implementation are you using? What format do the nodes need to be in to pass to that function? Specifically what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to connect all the nodes using any edge insertion algorithms.